# Webtrends REST API Limit

Tags: api, webtrends

Looking at the documentation i found this information :

*Data Extraction API requests are rate limited by number of requests and data download volume per unit of time (hour, day, week, or month). If you exceed the limit, a 403 error occurs.*

Someone could tell me more about this limit ? How many call per day/month/year ???

Comment: Why don't you get in touch with the WebTrends Support? Call them, they will answer you this question immediately. Don't forget then to answer your question here ;)

Comment: Nothing to do... i asked via twitter at Q&A official support but they never responded.

Comment: Open a supportcase or call them: http://www.webtrends.com/Support/Contact.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just spoke to webtrends support.  The limit is 600 requests per use per hour or 1 Gig per user per hour.